# Using geo_shape filter inside bool filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to combine a `geo_shape` Elasticsearch filter with a basic `term` filter within a `bool` filter, so I can attempt to improve performance of our elasticsearch query, with little success.

This query is used over a set of polygons in Elasticsearch, to determine which shapes the specified point is in.

It seems as though, unless I have the wrong end of the stick, `geo_shape` filters can't be included inside a `bool` filter collection like this:

```
{
"size": 1000,
"fields": [],
"query": {
"filtered": {
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "geo_shape": {
            "deliveryAreas.area": {
              "shape": {
                "coordinates": [
                  -0.126208,
                  51.430874
                ],
                "type": "point"
              }
            }
          }
          },
          {
           "term": {
            "restaurantState": 3
           }
          }
         ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The query above runs, but returns 0 results. Using the `geo_shape` query outside the `bool` works fine, but the combination of the two seems to fail. I assume it must be a syntax error, as the ElasticSearch docs recommend this approach to make the expensive geo calls cheaper, but no luck so far.

Comment: Not sure about this, but shouldn't you use a shape of type circle with a radius to be used in the filter? Feels like you now only get back an exact match of coordinates. Or is that what you want? Is it possible to provide the data you are testing with as well?

Comment: Apologies, a little more context: This query is used over a set of polygons in elasticsearch, to determine which shapes the specified point is in. The geo_shape filter works fine on it's own and returns a set of results, however it doesn't return any results in the configuration above.

Comment: a obviously dumb question but i'm good at so i ask the for the results returned by geoshape filter alone do they have a document with restaurantState 3 ?

Comment: Yes they do, also if you remove that filter from the query it still fails to return any results (where as the same query without the bool filter returns thousands).

Comment: Any solution to this @DaveMarsland?